# Python: How to add borders to images so they keep their aspect ratio

Tags: python, imageview, resize

How can I transform an Image so that if it's a Portrait:
[image]

it will get borders on the sides so that its aspect ratio is 1:1 or if it's a Landscape

[image]

it gets borders on top and bottom?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new image with `numpy.zeros()` with the proper size. Then copy your image to the new image.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. Give your image name as input. It writes an image with name result.jpg in the same directory

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread("your_image.jpg")
x,y=img.shape[:2]
ma=max(x,y)
blank = np.zeros((ma,ma,3), np.uint8)
if y>=x:
    blank[(y-x)/2:(y-x)/2+x,0:y]=img
else:
    blank[0:x,(x-y)/2:(x-y)/2+y]=img
cv2.imshow('result', blank)
cv2.imwrite("result.jpg",blank)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I'm using Pythonista on an iPhone which doesn't support cv2. Do you know any alternatives?

Comment: No idea but follow that algorithm to work things out